# How to use Rails to post to Woocommerce REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying write code using the Woocommerce REST API v. 3 with Ruby on Rails 6.

The Woocommerce shop is install by MAMP and run on localhost:8888 and Rails runs on localhost:3000.

I'm using the "[WooCommerce API - Ruby Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYTlA.png)" gem.

I just speedcoded to have something working and the refactor so this is my code right now:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  require 'woocommerce_api'
  require 'json'

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    woocommerce = WooCommerce::API.new(
      'http://localhost:8888/wordpress_rails/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
      'CLIENT_KEY',
      'CLIENT_SECRET',
      version: 'v3',
      wp_api: true,
      debug_mode: true
    )
    data = {
      name: 'Premium Quality',
      type: 'simple',
      regular_price: '290',
      description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
      fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor 
      sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris 
     placerat eleifend leo.',
  short_description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.'

    }

woocommerce.post('products', data).parsed_response
  end
end
```

When I post `data` with Postman to the same URL as above, the product is created but when I'm doing a post with Rails I get the `rest_no_route` error.

Here is my post with Postman:

[image: Create new product with Postman]

What is going wrong when I post to the REST API with Rails?

Comment: you don't have the good configuration, for "url" you have to put `http://localhost:8888/wordpress_rails/wordpress` and for version : `wc/v3`

Comment: Thank you!! That works!

Comment: Please read "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)". Also, [grammar, spelling and capitalization are important](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/153968) on SO. Help us maintain the site by taking the time to ensure your post meets the guidelines to the very best of your ability. Failing to do so can actually affect other user's willingness to help, so help us help you.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421